# Laravel HasManyDeep relationship

Tags: laravel, relationship, has-many-through

I have 3 tables

Company->ManyToMany->Activity->BelongsTo->chamber

i need to use HasmanyDeep to find all chambers related to specific company.
when i write this in **Company Model**, it returns empty

```
 public function chambers(){
    return $this->hasManyDeep('App\Models\Chamber',['activity_company','App\Models\Activity'],['activity_id','company_id'],['chamber_id']);
}
```

Comment: What is the package you are using ?

Comment: And also share the model columns

Answer (score 0):

I believe to inverse the relationship on the belongsTo relation, you can use the syntax [null, null, 'chamber_id'].

```
return $this->hasManyDeep(
    'App\Models\Chamber',
    [
        'activity_company',
        'App\Models\Activity',
    ],
    ['activity_id','company_id'],
    [null, null, 'chamber_id']
);
```

Comment: not worked , he believe now , the activity has many chambers , not belong to chamber, 'code' SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'chambers.activity_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `chambers`.*, `activity_company`.`company_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `chambers` inner join `activities` on `activities`.`id` = `chambers`.`activity_id` inner join `activity_company` on `activity_company`.`activity_id` = `activities`.`id` where `activity_company`.`company_id` = 29)

Comment: But your question said belongs to :) i will update in a minute or so

Comment: If it's not a has many deep, it must be an has one deep, where an activity only has one chamber or am i mistaken? updated the code.

Comment: Activity belong to one chamber , but company has many activities, so company will belong to many chambers too

Comment: Ok last try :) hasManyDeep is always hard, scoured through the documentation and i think you may get it to work with the syntax suggested in the edit